# Setting maximum TargetSDK for the apk

Tags: android, google-play, android-studio

I have a app on the Google Play with the following configuration. Till now I thought that Google Play uses `AndroidManifest` to determine the minimum and the maximum SdkVersion. Unfortunately as it reveals people could download and install this app on higher APIs.
The question is; how to set maximum API limit for this app (I guess I need to set `compileSdkVersion 17` in build.gradle but I have to be sure) before publish the apk.

AndroidManifest.xml (an extract):

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

build.gradle (an extract):

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
   //...
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set maximum api level ?

Comment: @holtaf because I'm not going to update it anymore and I know it doesn't work well with new APIs (and I don't have a time and don't want to fix it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting targetSdk Version and minSdkVersion

maxSDK Version is a different attribute.

but is discouraged to set it

heres the full version of the code, from developer.android.com

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Google play store indirectly choose the version ,after upload of the apk it looks after our android manifest.xml from there it takes all the information like **minsdkversion** and **maxsdkversion** in that manner our app will support based on that values it contain..